# Angular 10 | Typescript | Vars assigned inside change event are undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I init an algolia input and assign an onchange event to the input. This happens in a service.

```
algolia_data;
random_var;
this.http.post<any>('APIENDPOINT', formData).subscribe(data => {
  instance = places({
    appId: this.ALGO_APPLICATION_ID,
    apiKey: data['data'],
    container: algoliaInput,
    type: 'city',
    language: localStorage.getItem('lang')
  }); 
  instance.on('change', function resultSelected(e) {
    console.log(e);
    this.algolia_data = {};
    this.algolia_data['latitude'] = e.suggestion.latlng.lat;
    this.algolia_data['longitude'] = e.suggestion.latlng.lng;
    this.algolia_data['country'] = e.suggestion.countryCode.toUpperCase();
    this.algolia_data['city'] = e.suggestion.name;
    this.algolia_data['zipcode'] = e.suggestion.postcode;
    this.algolia_data['search_user_city_google_reg'] = e.suggestion.name;
    console.log(this.algolia_data);
    this.random_var = "has value";
  });
});
```

Everytime the change event triggers when I enter something into the input the `console.log` displays the values correctly.

BUT some time later I have an other function, which should access the values, but it tells me `undefined`. This happens in a component where I import the service:

```
StartRegistration() {
  console.log(this.dataService.algolia_data); // undefined
  console.log(this.dataService.random_var); // undefined
}
```

I have no clue why this happens as the second function is called later. I also do not reload the page or change the route.

Comment: try to use arrow function  `(e) =>` instead of `function resultSelected(e)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using normal function instead of [arrow function](https://javascript.info/arrow-functions-basics).

Unlike regular functions **(which has its own `this` thats why its not workinging your case)**, arrow functions do not have their own `this`. The value of this inside an arrow function remains the same throughout the lifecycle of the function and is always bound to the value of this in the closest non-arrow parent function.

**NOTE:** Arrow function is recommended here and defining `this` into a variable and then using it i.e `let self = this;` not recommended.

```
this.http.post<any>('APIENDPOINT', formData).subscribe(data => {
  instance = places({
  appId: this.ALGO_APPLICATION_ID,
  apiKey: data['data'],
  container: algoliaInput,
  type: 'city',
  language: localStorage.getItem('lang')
}); 
instance.on('change', (e) => {
  console.log(e);
  this.algolia_data = {};
  this.algolia_data['latitude'] = e.suggestion.latlng.lat;
  this.algolia_data['longitude'] = e.suggestion.latlng.lng;
  this.algolia_data['country'] = e.suggestion.countryCode.toUpperCase();
  this.algolia_data['city'] = e.suggestion.name;
  this.algolia_data['zipcode'] = e.suggestion.postcode;
  this.algolia_data['search_user_city_google_reg'] = e.suggestion.name;

  this.random_var = "has value";
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try by changing `function resultSelected(e)` to

`instance.on('change', (e)=> { //rest of code`

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common mistake in javascript/typescript. The 'this' value inside an event handler represents the event. You can solve this like so:

```js
let self = this;
this.http.post<any>('APIENDPOINT', formData).subscribe(data => {
  instance = places({
    appId: this.ALGO_APPLICATION_ID,
    apiKey: data['data'],
    container: algoliaInput,
    type: 'city',
    language: localStorage.getItem('lang')
  }); 
  instance.on('change', function resultSelected(e) {
    console.log(e);
    self.algolia_data = {};
    self.algolia_data['latitude'] = e.suggestion.latlng.lat;
    self.algolia_data['longitude'] = e.suggestion.latlng.lng;
    self.algolia_data['country'] = e.suggestion.countryCode.toUpperCase();
    self.algolia_data['city'] = e.suggestion.name;
    self.algolia_data['zipcode'] = e.suggestion.postcode;
    self.algolia_data['search_user_city_google_reg'] = e.suggestion.name;
    console.log(self.algolia_data);
    this.random_var = "has value";
  });
});
```

Cheers!

Comment: this is not the best way to fix this at all. other answers recommending to use an arrow function are the preferred. assigning `this` to a variable is really only advised in cases where you need or want multiple `this` contexts